# Is there a free to use validated Computer Science concept inventory?

Tags: assessment

I'm looking for a multiple-choice assessment to determine the efficacy of an introductory CS program. Preferably validated with some research and free to use but both of those requirements are flexible. Something language agnostic like the [SCS1](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3374135.3385321) would be preferred though I've had difficulty getting access to the text of that assessment.

Comment: Say something about the course level. "Introductory" can mean a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://teachcomputing.org/curriculum/key-stage-4

Perhaps Algorithms 1-2 is what matches best your request. Though it's assessments are mixed, not just MC, and Python-inspired.